# values and columns are separated with "/"

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, dataset, multiple-columns

I was dealing with a raw dataset, and when I looked at it from numbers application of mac, it seemed normal.
However, when I did `read_csv()` in R, I encountered an error. the problem is that all columns appear as one single column and this goes same for rows as well.
For example, when I was searching for column names they appeared as a single column like the following:

```
data$column_A column_B
```

And when I called `head()` with the first two rows, they appeared as follows.

```
Expected Tibble: 
 
column_A column_B 
1        "A"
2        "B"

Output Tibble: 

column_A\tcolumn_B
"1\tA"
"2\tB"
```

What is the reason that columns and values appear all together and that when I searched for the column, they appear altogether with spaces between column names? I not only don't know what the specific problems are, but I also couldn't find a discussion about this. How can I fix this?

Sorry for my English. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Is this tabbed delimited data? With `read_csv()` can you try setting `delim = "\t"`? Or instead try using `read_tsv()`?

Comment: `\t` = TAB, if you were wondering.

Comment: `read_tsv()` worked but what is the reason? How did it work because the file is in csv format.

Comment: Your Computer does not really care about the file formats. They are more of a suggestion for a System to open certain files with certain programs (.docx for Word etc.).  Your File Values not Comma Separated (**CS**V), but Tab-separated (**TS**V). Same Idea as CSV but different delimiter (TAB('\t') instead of ",").